# Database design - table design for modeling a hierarchy

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, erd

I am designing a laboratory information system (LIS) and am confused on how to design the tables for the different laboratory tests. How should I deal with a table that has an attribute with multiple values and each of the multiple values of that attribute can also have multiple values as well?

Here's some of the data in my LIS design...

```
    HEMATOLOGY  <-------- Lab group
    **************************************************************
     CBC        <-------- Sub group 1
       RBC      <-------- Component
       WBC
       Hemoglobin
       Hematocrit
       MCV
       MCH
       MCHC
       Platelet count
     Hemoglobin
     Hematocrit
     WBC differential
       Neutrophils
       Lymphocytes
       Monocytes
       Eosinophils
       Basophils
     Platelet count
     Reticulocyte count
     ESR
     Bleeding time
     Clotting time
     Pro-time
     Peripheral smear
     Malarial smear
     ABO
     RH typing

    CLINICAL MICROSCOPY       <-------- Lab Group
    **************************************************************
     Routine urinalysis       <-------- Sub group 1
       Visual Examination     <-------- Sub group 2
         Color                <-------- Component
         Turbidity
         Specific Gravity       
       Chemical Examination
         pH
         protein
         glucose
         ketones
         RBC
         Hbg
         bilirubin
         specific gravitiy
         nitrite for bacteria
         urobilinogen
         leukocyte esterase 
       Microscopic Examination
         Red Blood Cells (RBCs)
         White Blood Cells (WBCs)
         Epithelial Cells 
         Microorganisms (bacteria, trichomonads, yeast) 
         Trichomonads 
         Casts 
         Crystals
     Occult Blood
     Pregnancy Test
```

...This hierarchy of data also gets repeated in other lab groupings in my design (e.g. Blood chemistry, Serology, etc)...

Another question is, how am I gonna deal with a component (for example, RBC) which can be a member of one or more lab groups?

I already implemented a solution to my problem by making a separate tables, 1 for lab group,  1 for sub group 1, 1 for sub group 2 and 1 for component. And then created another table to consolidate all of them by placing a foreign key of each in this table...the only trade off is that some of the rows in this table may have null values. Im not satisfied with my design, so I'm hoping someone could give me advise on how to make it right; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple options:

If it is just the hierarchy above you are modeling, and there is no other data involved, then you can do it in two tables:

[image: two table model]

One problem with this is that you do not enforce that, for example, a `sub_group` must be a child of a `lab_group`, or that a `component` must be child of either a `sub_group_1` or a `sub_group_2`, but you could enforce these requirements in your application tier instead.

The plus side of this approach is that the schema is nice and simple. Even if the entities have more data associated with them, it might still be worth modeling the hierarchy like this and have some separate tables for the entities themselves.

If you want to enforce the correct relationships at the data level, then you are going to have to split it out into separate tables. Maybe something like this:

[image: mutiple tables]

This assumes that each `sub_group_1` is only related to a single `lab_group`. If this is not the case then add a link table between `lab_group` and `sub_group_1`. Likewise for the `sub_group_1` -> `sub_group_2` relationship.

There is a single link table between `component` and `sub_group_1` and `sub_group_2`. This allows a single `component` to be related to several `sub_group_1` and `sub_group_2` entities. The fact it is a single table means that a lot of the `sub_group_1_id` and `sub_group_2_id` records will be `null` (like you mentioned in your question). You could prevent the nulls be having two separate link tables:

- `sub_group_1_component` with a foreign key to `sub_group_1` and a foreign key to `component`
- `sub_group_2_component` with a foreign key to `sub_group_2` and a foreign key to `component`

The reason I didn't put this in the diagram is that for me, having to query two tables rather than one to get all the `component` -> `sub_group` relationships is too much of a pain. For the sake of a little denormalisation (allowing a few `nulls`) it is much easier to query a single table. If you find yourself allowing a lot of `null`s (like a single link table for the relationships between all the entities here) then that is probably denormalising too much.

Comment: Hi, first of all i wanna thank you for your reply, i've been thinking about your second suggestion as it was supposed to be my first approach in my design but i ran into some problems with that regarding queries as you said since it would be too much pain in querying two tables rather than just one. Another reason why i didn't use that approach is because i can't use a query like for example, "looking for a list of components that belongs to a certain lab_group." Is it wrong to put a relationship between the lab_groups and the components in this kind of design?

Comment: I would try to avoid putting a foreign key between `lab_group` and `component` if possible. The reason being that it duplicates data and you no longer have a single source of truth. This can be a pain if your `lab_group` -> `component` relationship goes out of sync with your other relationships, which one do you believe? You should be able to write a query to get all components for a single lab_group without having to add any new relationships. Here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f90f/17/0

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would create 3 tables using relationships for the values. It gives you the ability to create limitless arrays of values. Just try to make sure you give great column names, or your head will spin for days. :)

Also, null values aren't a problem look into all the different type of joins